# React Native: Remove Expo Cookies

Tags: react-native, cookies, fetch, expo, credentials

I'm building a Expo/React Native app where I use fetch and credentials (cookies) to log into a server.

**The code works properly and looks like this:**

```
login = async (email, password) => {
    try {    
        var body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });

        const response = await fetch('http://10.0.2.2/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              username: username,
              password: password
            })
        });

        if(response.hasOwnProperty('accessToken'))
        {
          console.log('login successfull');
          console.log(response);
        }
        else if(response.hasOwnProperty('error'))
        {
          console.log('login failed');
          console.log(response)
        } 
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.log('error: ' + e);
    }
};
```

**My problem is, that React Native does not log out when I stop the app. I dont want to manually logout by API call.**

Is there a way like in React Web, where I simply removed the cookies from Chrome and then I am logged out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using expo then you could try :

```
expo r -c
```

this would clear your project's cache and run expo

Comment: This doesn't appear to work, at least on iOS

Comment: Actually I only use android and therefore I don't know anything about iOS but I think this should work on iOS as this command has nothing to do with platform

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clearCookies` function from `RCTNetworking` to clear the cookies:

```
const RCTNetworking = require('RCTNetworking');
RCTNetworking.clearCookies((result) => {
console.log(result) //true if successfully cleared
});
```

I can confirm that it works on Android and expo. For iOS, I think it is fixed with this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/9264 .

Comment: This does not appear to be working on iOS for me sadly